# What is this code for in the head of the DiscoverWestworld.com website?

Tags: javascript, html, app-secret

I happen to be looking at the code for the [DiscoverWestsworld.com](https://www.discoverwestworld.com/#) website and noticed something I've never seen before in the .

Does anyone know what this is for?

[image: code of DiscoverWestworld.com homepage]

Comment: It's called a Shadow DOM. More info can be found on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate. Now I know what a Shadow DOM is. Thanks to @Gavin